# How to get result after filter db on discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js, quick.db

I want to get the result from filter of db but I got undefined and I don't know why.

```
const IDD = discordsearchf
const all = (await client.db.all()).filter(data => data.id.startsWith("tickets_"));
const mfilter = all.filter(data => data.value.creator === IDD && data.value.createdAt == '1678356812821');

const efilter = mfilter.filter(data => data.value.closedBy)   

console.log(efilter)
```

Here I got undefined:

```
const efilter = mfilter.filter(data => data.value.closedBy)   
console.log(efilter)
```

Here is cmd for console log mfilter:

```
[
  {
    id: 'tickets_1083331733912559716',
    value: {
      id: 136,
      category: [Object],
      reason: 'No reason provided',
      creator: '909068597089959976',
      invited: [],
      createdAt: 1678356812821,
      claimed: false,
      claimedBy: null,
      claimedAt: null,
      closed: true,
      closedBy: '715637000669102171',
      closedAt: 1678562559496,
      acceptedby: '846304823595106304',
      messageId: '1083331735191814184',
      closeReason: 'No REASON'
    }
  }
]
```

I tried `value.closedBy`, `data.value.closedBy`, and `mfilter.closedBy`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `mfilter` with this line:

```js
const mfilter = all.filter(data => data.value.creator === IDD && data.value.createdAt == 1678356812821);
```

`data.value.createdAt` here is a **Number** and as I can see in your code you used the string quotes `' '` when checking the filter condition `data.value.createdAt == '1678356812821'`.
So removing the string quotes would probably solve the problem.
Your code should look now like this:

```js
const IDD = discordsearchf
const all = (await client.db.all()).filter(data => data.id.startsWith("tickets_"));
const mfilter = all.filter(data => data.value.creator === IDD && data.value.createdAt == 1678356812821);

const efilter = mfilter.filter(data => data.value.closedBy)   
        
console.log(efilter)
```

Comment: here is got again